# Neoclipse editing and constant graph layout

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, neoclipse

Each time I add a new node and a relationship, **Neoclipse change the layout of the graph and eclipses nodes according to the traversal path**, which become annoying as the graph is growing very fast (hundreds of nodes). 
Each time, I have to find the newly created node to add properties.

My question: **Is there any option that allows to disable remapping the graph each time it is edited**

The button "Show reference node" alleviates the issue by keeping focus a given node, but I am looking for a way to disable the graph redrawing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I asked around and right now that's the current behavior, we would have to change something in the code. Care to check out the new Neo4j Browser to add nodes with properties and relationships using cypher?

Comment: Actually, I have made my choice, for now I am using Neo4j server for editing the nodes though still struggling with Cypher.